# How to make store bought whole multi grain bread softer?

Tags: bread, grains

I normally don't like sandwiches in the first place, but if I eat sandwiches, I find sandwiches made with white bread to be more appetizing, since the bread is soft and smooth

When I tried whole grain bread instead, the bread is highly textured and hard. Is there something I can do to make the texture of whole grain bread more palatable?

Comment: What brands of multigrain bread do you have qualms with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done in the past is mist some water on both sides of the bread slices, then put them in the microwave for 10-15 seconds (alternatively, an oven set at 300F/150C for 5-10 minutes will do it too).

Experiment with the amount of water (but keep it low) and cooking times. You should get much softer (and warm) bread slices out of it.

Comment: Sounds fast and simple. I'll give it a try. Do you know if the bread will stay soft for lunch if I prepare it after dinner the day before?

Comment: I usually do this when preparing to eat the sandwich itself, so I've never tested it, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend toasting your whole grain bread in a frying pan with butter before making your sandwich. The butter imparts a nice flavor and helps prevent burning. Toasting using cooking oil (olive oil is a nice substitute) also helps with flavor and texture. You can even use butter and oil together.